# WPF binding inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I'm learing WPF, it's fun but very confusing. I am currently trying to get values from `DataTemplate`. Simple `Binding = {Binding Value}` is not recognized. How can I get values of elements iside `DataTemplate`? Following code only displays Value:

```
        <ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <DataGrid x:Name="appSettingsData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="7" CanUserAddRows="False" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="textBox">
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <!-- This is place from where I'm trying to take values -->
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}"  />
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>                                
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: DataTemplate for which control? Please paste your xaml and full code here, not understanding what you are looking for.

Comment: @RavirajPalvankar is it more clear now?

Comment: Simply add DataType to DataTemplate. E.g <DataTemplate DataType={x:Type viewModels:YourType} ... >

Comment: @MaciekŚ. I have one little problem with that ``viewModels is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.``

Comment: sorry for confusing you: viewModels is a namespace of YourType.

Comment: @MaciekŚ. I'm going to lose my hair because of this technology soon. VS  Intellisense is forcing me to write ``DataType="{x:Type local:ExpanseItHome}"`` and ``DataType="{x:Type ExpanseItHome:...}"`` do not offer anything, and forcing variables and types there doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Kajbo - how can we help you here, if you didn't reveal any secrets about your code? Or just try to make the smallest possible working example and try to crunch it yourself. If your Value is of type ExpanseItHome, then VS Intellisens is correct, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you complicating things?
Your controls should be in the first DataTemplate itself:

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Margin="10,10,10,10">
            <DataGrid x:Name="appSettingsData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="7" CanUserAddRows="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" Width="*">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}">
                                        <TextBlock.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="textBox">
                                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </TextBlock.Style>
                                    </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```